# Sybase like clause for matching a pattern between the string

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to build a sybase ASE query to match lastname, firstname for a person. There are few different formats for name. It can be "lastname, firstname" OR it can be "lastname,firstname" (no space in between , and firstname). I have tried using name like 'lastname[,][ ]firstname' but it does not work. I can not use lastname,%firstname as it would match with any character for firstname. The valid character is either space or nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `SAP/Sybase ASE` does not provide support for regex patterns (eg, 'zero or more spaces'), so you're left with a few basic options ...

`union (all)` two queries:

```
select  *
from    names_table
where   name like 'lastname, firstname'

union all

select  *
from    names_table
where   name like 'lastname,firstname'
```

**NOTE**: Both queries should use an index on the `name` column assuming statistics show an index access plan is the best option.

`or` two `where` clauses:

```
select  *
from    names_table
where   (name like 'lastname, firstname' or name like 'lastname,firstname')
```

**NOTE**: Whether or not this uses an index on the `name` column will depend on the statistics for the index and column and/or the complexity of the actual query.

Strip out spaces and match what's left:

```
select  *
from    names_table
where   str_replace(name,' ',null) like 'lastname,firstname'
```

**NOTE**: In most cases this will disable the use of an index on the `name` column.

---

From an indexing perspective ...

If you need to run this type of query often, and the performance of said query is less than acceptable, you could look at a couple additional indexing options:

- (materialized) computed column + index on said computed column
- function-based index (`ASE` basically creates a 'system' computed column under the covers and then creates the index on said column)

Comment: thanks @markp-fuso for various approaches. Unfortunately we can not go with any of the option. We are looking at the database to make names consistent and always have a space when there are two names. Appreciate your insight.